# Maven Dependency is not getting downloaded in the eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

1. JDK path is set and added preferences as well.
2. Maven path is set and working fine.
3. TestNG added to the project.
4. Tried to Delete the .m2 folder as well and after that update project.
   Below error is coming when I have imported a maven project try to Update it.

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Please find the detailed image for the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRzny.png)

Comment: Please run a build with "clean package" and report the error messages.

Comment: Run on plain command line as J Fabian Meier suggests...

Comment: There may be an issue with pom.xml, otherwise, the issue may be with build-path.